# PySide. Extracting DOM HTML. AccessNetworkmanager

Tags: javascript, python, html, dom, pyside

I need to extract all calendar data from page like
"http://www.dukascopy.com/swiss/english/marketwatch/calendars/eccalendar/". Firstly - to extract all html with inner dom.
Using eclipse and Python 3.3, win7. Searched here answers, and coded smth based on them.
Looks like:

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtDeclarative
from PySide.QtGui import QApplication, QDesktopServices, QImage, QPainter
from PySide.QtCore import QByteArray, QUrl, QTimer, QEventLoop, QIODevice, QObject
from PySide.QtWebKit import QWebFrame, QWebView, QWebPage, QWebSettings
from PySide.QtNetwork import QNetworkAccessManager, QNetworkProxy, QNetworkRequest, QNetworkReply, QNetworkDiskCache
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
web = QWebView()
web.load(QUrl("http://www.dukascopy.com/swiss/english/marketwatch/calendars/eccalendar/"))
web.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
"""
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = QWebView()
request = QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://www.dukascopy.com/swiss/english/marketwatch/calendars/eccalendar/"))
reply = w.page().networkAccessManager().get(request)
print(reply)
byte_array = reply.readAll()
plist = reply.rawHeaderList()
print(plist)
print(byte_array)
```

When loading page to QWebView() it works fine (commented code), but I couldn't find how to extract all html from QWebView(). So i tried via "request" - decommented code. And nothing prints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with signals:

```
def print_content():
     print web.page().mainFrame().toHtml() # or toPlainText()
     # or
     # print web.page().currentFrame().toHtml() # or toPlainText()
```

and

```
web.page().mainFrame().loadFinished.connect(print_content)
# or web.loadFinished.connect(print_content)
web.load(QUrl("http://www.dukascopy.com/swiss/english/marketwatch/calendars/eccalendar/"))
web.show()
```

`print_content` should be called then loadFinished signal arrives

Comment: Added such code (to both variants)
`h1 = web.page().mainFrame().toHtml() # or toPlainText()
t1 = web.page().mainFrame().toPlainText()
h2 = web.page().currentFrame().toHtml() # or toPlainText()
t2 = web.page().currentFrame().toPlainText()
print(h1)
print(h2)
print(t1)
print(t2) `


But it prints only "ToHTML" and only this
"<html><head></head><body></body></html>
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
"

Comment: Ok, new variant looks more beautyful. But there is the same trouble as it was, when I used other scrappers ('selenium', 'html_dom' etc). The table I need is a result of javascript. Here "print web.page().mainFrame().toHtml()" prints the js-code but not result. How can i get a result of javascript? For example like firefox "view source of selected element".

Comment: @user3003873 short answer - you must execute javascript, or render page to get result. It is a browser task

Comment: I am sorry, may be it's obviously, but I am totally novice in such themes. I found only this about executing js.  frame.evaluateJavaScript("alert('Hello');") But there is a necessary argument - js code. And I didn't find how to execute EXISTING on the page code .